# Typescript, styled-component error: TS2769: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

This is my styledComponent:

```
const stopPropagation = (event: Event): void => {
  event.stopPropagation();
};

<StyledComp onClick={stopPropagation}> //error occurs here
    hi StyledComp
</StyledComp>
```

and this is how I defined it:

```
export type Prop = {
  onClick: (event: Event) => void;
};

export const StyledComp = styled.div<Prop>`
  display: flex;
`;
```

But it returns an error like:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>, "title" | "slot" | ... 252 more ... | "is"> & { ...; } & StyledComp, "title" | ... 254 more ... | "is"> & Partial<...>, "title" | ... 254 more ... | "is"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.     Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) & ((event: Event) => void)'.       Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.         Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.           Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'Event'.             Types of property 'target' are incompatible.               Property 'value' is missing in type 'EventTarget' but required in type '{ value: string; }'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, StyledComp, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"div", any, StyledComp, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.     Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) & ((event: Event) => void)'.       Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.

**Note**: You can find styled-component&Typescript docs [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript)!

**Edit:**

This is **Event** type:

```
export type Event = {
  target: {
    value: string;
  };
  stopPropagation: () => void;
  preventDefault: () => void;
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `Event` exactly is, but AFAIK there is no such a built-in static type. So if you did not define it manually, you have to use `React.MouseEvent` instead.

Comment: I defined it manually it's the same as React.MouseEvent.

Comment: Oh Maybe I'm wrong about Event type. let me investigate maybe it is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part of the error message is

> Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void'

So the `onClick` property of a styled div has the type `(event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void` and you want to assign a function of type `(event: Event) => void` to it, but this does not work, because the types are incompatible.

You should write instead:

```
const stopPropagation = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>): void => {
  event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I added this type :   React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>
and It worked.

Comment: Just wanted to add a little note to this correct answer. This answer is correct as long as you import the MouseEvent from the react like this: `import { MouseEvent } from 'react'`. The MouseEvent for Restrictive Event Handling is unnecessary and meaningless so if you want to use Restrictive approach you can do it like: `MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` or for general usage you can simply use `MouseEvent` alone.